# Page scroll does not work after redirect nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Im using nextJs version 13.5.4

I'm redirecting to a page from a server component using the nextjs redirect function. After the redirection the next page does not have the scroll bar and the page is stuck in one place. I can see the it automatically set the overflow to hidden.

```
element.style {
    padding-right: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? After a refresh it works as expected. I also don't have any overflow: hidden in my globals.css

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect` hook can be used to add the overflow: auto property to the body element after the redirect

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

useEffect(() => {
  document.body.style.overflow = 'auto';
}, []);
```

to only set temporarily so not to affect the rest of the page's functionality.

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

useEffect(() => {
  // save previous value
  const previousOverflow = document.body.style.overflow;

  // set overflow to auto
  document.body.style.overflow = 'auto';

  // cleanup function to restore previous value on unmount
  return () => {
    document.body.style.overflow = previousOverflow;
  }
}, []);
```

Comment: Where should I place the above code? since in my case the redirection is happening inside a server ('use server') component not in the client code.